# Custom Fields, Media uploader, Attachments

Tags: attachments

I have added Custom Fields to the Media Uploader in WP3.5. I am unsure of how to have that data displayed on the Attachment page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to get your values. One way is in the loop and another way is outside the loop. Here is a short code snippet that can be used to get them outside the loop

```
 ( untested )
 <?php 
   global $wp_query;
   $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
   echo get_post_meta($postid, 'customField', true);
?>
```

You will want to change the 'customField' in the last line above to the name of your custom field

You might also read up in the codex 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Here is another good source for you to look over
http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/wordpress/custom-fields/

I would also try googling for some results on how to display them. There are tons of articles out there that will answer your question much faster than waiting for a response.